# Aspnetboilerplate Encrypt decrypt entity

Tags: c#, encryption, entity-framework-core, orm, aspnetboilerplate

I am attempting to decrypt and encrypt an entity property based on an attribute. Now i could do this in an application service at the point the DTO is Created or Updated and then on a Get (Read) I can then decrypt it.

I can solve this problem for say a specific entity for a particular service, but I will have an issue when the entity is linked to another. I don't want to have to call a decrypt method and use reflection to check for an attribute, in any subclasses for all entities.

Is there any suggestions? For example maybe I could subscribe to the materialise event on the entity, and check the entity has IEncrypt attribute and in turn could therefore decrypt any properties with this attribute.

An example

```
public class WindowsUser : Entity, IMayHaveTenant
{
   [Required] [StringLength(260)] 
   public string Username { get; set; }

   [Encrypt]
   [Required]
   public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I can encrypt/decrypt this in the WindowsUserAppService perfectly fine.

Now if I have a Domain and you can include WindowsUsers I have to do a decrypt in here as well. Now that is not a problem for a single entity, but if I have many entities that all have foreign keys to WindowsUser I now need to implement a decrypt in all services that may include it.

```
public class Domain : Entity, IMayHaveTenant
{
  [Required]
  [StringLength(260)]
  public string DomainName { get; set; }

  public ICollection<WindowsUser> WindowsUsers { get; set; }

  public int? TenantId { get; set; }
}
```

For Encryption I could intercept in the saving on context

```
public DbContext(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options)
: base(options)
{
   this.SavingChanges += DbContext_SavingChanges;
}
```

But this only solves the writes and the reads are where I need to decrypt for all entities that may include / have a foreign key to a entity with a field for encryption.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Which EF Core version?

Comment: Why do not use `HasConversion`?

Comment: When you say HasConversion ? What are you referring to?

Comment: I mean [Value Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations)

Comment: Yes that's a really good pointer, I will do some testing with it and I expect it will resolve my problem. I just need to think about DI for an Encryption service

Comment: Only when configuring Model. I don't think DI is suitable here.

Comment: The value converter works really well. Now the only scenario that i would like to cater for would be to update the encryption salt. Any ideas how you could possibly update entities to one decrypt on the old salt and then encrypt on another one.

Answer (score 0):

As per Svyatoslav comments using a ValueConverter<string, string> will resolve the problem.

An example code is to use

```
 internal class StringEncryptionConverter : ValueConverter<string, string> 
 {
    private class Wrapper {
            private readonly IUserEncryption encryptionDecryptionService;

            public Wrapper(IUserEncryption encryptionDecryptionService) {
                    this.encryptionDecryptionService =
                        encryptionDecryptionService;
            }

            public Expression<Func<string, string>> To => x =>
                x != null ? encryptionDecryptionService.Encrypt(x) : null;

            public Expression<Func<string, string>> From => x =>
                x != null ? encryptionDecryptionService.Decrypt(x) : null;
    }

    public StringEncryptionConverter(
        IUserEncryption encryptionDecryptionService,
        ConverterMappingHints mappingHints = default)
        : this(new Wrapper(encryptionDecryptionService), mappingHints) {}

    StringEncryptionConverter(Wrapper wrapper,
                              ConverterMappingHints mappingHints)
        : base(wrapper.To, wrapper.From, mappingHints) {}
}
```

Then in the DB context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    modelBuilder.Entity<WindowsUser>(winUser => {
            winUser.Property(w => w.Password)
                .HasConversion(new StringEncryptionConverter(
                    userEncryptionDecryptionService));
    });
}
```

Dont forget add the userEncryptionDecryptionService service into the class constructor.